# When must I choose between doing firestore read and write operations in a firestore trigger function or directly calling firestore in an api endpoint

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In this program, when a task is created and assigned to a user, Firestore will increment the `numberOfTasksAssigned` field.

**Option 1:** Write Firestore Document in an express API endpoint.

```js
 try {
    const newTaskRef = db
      .collection("organizations")
      .doc(req.user.userData.organization)
      .collection("tasks")
      .doc();
    await newTaskRef.set({
      taskId: newTaskRef.id,
      name,
      user: {
        userId,
        username
      },
      organization: req.user.userData.organization,
      project: {
        projectId: req.body.project.projectid,
        name: req.body.project.name
      },
      completed: false,
    });
    // await db.doc(`/organizations/${req.user.displayName.slice(-20)}/users/${userId}`).update({
    //   numberOfTasksAssigned: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    // })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err, message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
```

**Option 2:** Write Firestore Document in a Firestore Trigger Function

```js
exports.updateUserTasks = functions.region("asia-east2").firestore.document(`/organizations/{organizationid}/tasks/{taskid}`)
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  try {
    await db.doc(`/organizations/${context.params.organizationid}/users/${snap.data().user.userId}`).update({
      numberOfTasksAssigned: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({error: err, message: "Something went wrong"})
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, the only difference I can see (with the info you provide) is a potential problem of access rights that a user could use to decrement the value of `numberOfTasksAssigned`.

We don't know if your express API endpoint is [implemented through Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps) and if you have implement some access rights through security rules, but with Option 1, it seems that a user could potentially directly modify his/her user document and decrement the value of `numberOfTasksAssigned`.

Using a Cloud Function to do the increment and prohibit direct update of the users document through Security Rules would avoid this problem: since Cloud Functions use the Admin SDK, they bypass Security Rules.

---

Another point to be noted is that you should probably execute the two writes in an atomic operation.

Comment: Will it be possible to avoid possible security risks, if instead of writing security rules, I would instead use if checks in the function?
```javascript
if (!( isAdmin(req.user.userData.branch) ||isHead(req.user.userData.position) ||req.user.uid=== req.body.project.lead))
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "You are not authorized to create a task for this project.",  });
```
I've used an authentication middleware to determine before accessing an API if the user is a part of the organization's database.
**The express API is implemented through cloud functions**